# How to take into account positive and negative amounts - best practice?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've put together some test data to explain my problem

Basically I have an OldBalance, and a CurrentBalance, and I'm trying to show what the difference is between them with the correct signage.

I'm doing this currently:

```
CurrentBalance-OldBalance as CurrentCalculation
```

You can see however with Row 3 that I'm getting a difference of -445.26, but I'm expecting a result of -376.20 as that's how Row 3 got from 34.53 to -410.73, Likewise with Row 4.

What am I missing here?

[image]

```
Create Table #temp
(
    CurrentBalance money,
    OldBalance money,
    ExpectedResult money
)

insert into #temp
(
    CurrentBalance,
    OldBalance,
    ExpectedResult
)

select
    100,
    200,
    -100
union all
select
    200,
    100,
    100
union all
select
    -100,
    100,
    -200
union all
select
    100,
    -100,
    200
union all
select
    -100,
    -200,
    100
union all
select
    -200,
    -100,
    -100
union all
select
-410.73,    
34.53,
-376.20


select
    *,
    CurrentBalance-OldBalance as CurrentCalculation
from 
    #temp

drop table #temp
```

Comment: umm, isnt `-410.73 - 34,53` results in `-445.26`? i think you will need some ifs.

Comment: BagusTesa - sure does, which was where I started, but realised in testing the data that it is in fact incorrect and giving false numbers. 
HABO - no, as there can be negative numbers in CurrentBalance as per my example which are correct.

Comment: `CurrentBalance - Sign( CurrentBalance ) * OldBalance` gives the expected results, but I don't know what it means. (My prior, now deleted, comment was quite incorrect.)

Comment: mathematically is correct, what you need is some if, rather case as shown on the answer below.

Comment: Thanks @HABO - what do you mean by you don't know what it means?

Comment: what is your rational of doing this ?

Comment: @Philip I'm used to credits and debits and how they affect balances. I'd expect the difference between a current balance and an old balance to be either a net credit or debit. Why the calculation would depend on the sign of one value is a mystery: `CurrentBalance - OldBalance` is how you got from the past to now.

Comment: I seems you're just subtracting ABS(current) - ABS(old), but I agree with @HABO, the why is a mystery. On my planet, if I had 34.53 yesterday and -410.73 today, somewhere I spent 445.26.

Comment: @GertArnold But that doesn't explain why the expected result in row 3 is _negative_, when in fact the ABS difference would be positive.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You're right. In fact it's -(ABS(current) - ABS(old)), or -(ABS(current) - old), but the basic thing is subtracting with absolute numbers. I don't know, but how does that make sense?

Comment: @Philip Can you explain the meaning of the amount `-376.20`? What does it express?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to handle this, using a `CASE` expression to determine the sign used to combine the current and old balance columns:

```
SELECT
    CurrentBalance,
    OldBalance,
    CASE WHEN CurrentBalance > OldBalance
         THEN CurrentBalance - OldBalance
         ELSE CurrentBalance + OldBalance END AS ExpectedResult
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

**Edit:**

We *could* write the query in a slightly more succinct way as:

```
SELECT
    CurrentBalance,
    OldBalance,
    CurrentBalance +
        (CASE WHEN CurrentBalance > OldBalance THEN -1.0 ELSE 1.0 END) * OldBalance AS ExpectedResult
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, that failed on a particular test case I forgot to include, could you please check my edited initial post?

Comment: I would actually question your data first before questioning my answer.  If my answer really does fail, then it means you have more than one set of logic.

Comment: I've just checked the data and the data is definitely correct. I just missed that particular use-case.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and show sample data for all combinations, positive and negative, greater and smaller.  There are still other edge cases which you have not yet included.

Comment: Thanks Tim, have done so. I think that covers all possible use-cases

Comment: Doesn't help at all.  I can't easily read your data.  Edit your sample data with all combinations of inputs and outputs.

Comment: Sorry Tim, I'm a bit confused what you're asking. I've included sample data there with all the combinations of positive/negative values and what the expected result is.  Could you please mention what sort of further sample data you're searching for?